# Cannot find any provider supporting AES/GCM/NoPadding

Tags: java, encryption, aes-gcm

We are trying to do encryption supporting AES/GCM/NoPadding in **java 7** getting below exception.

**Cannot find any provider supporting AES/GCM/NoPadding**

Code sample for generating cipher instance is below.

```
SecretKeySpec eks = new SecretKeySpec(k, "AES");
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, eks, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This cipher is not supported by Java 7 SE ([exception for Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : provider.entrySet()) {
            if (((String) entry.getValue()).contains("GCM")) {
                System.out.printf("key: [%s]  value: [%s]%n",
                    entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might have a look at [Bouncy Castle](https://bouncycastle.org/) as service provider in that case.

Small snippet for using Bouncycastle.

1. download `bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar` from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
2. register the service provider in your code

   ```
   Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
   ```
3. then you are able to use the cipher as (the paramter `"BC"` specifies to use Bounce Castle as service provider, can be omitted if there is no other provider for the same cipher)

   ```
   Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPADDING", "BC");
   ```

Java 8 support the cipher out of the box with

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPADDING");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information,do you have any sample code how to use AES/GCM/Padding with Bounty Castle,really appreciate.

Comment: @RE350 I added the necessary lines into my answer. The main thing you need to do is to register the new service provider.